# Using characteristics and picard iteration to solve nonlinear wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

My question:

I want to solve $u_{tt}-u_{xx}+\lambda u=0$ in $0 \leq |t|\leq x \leq 1$ with the conditions that $u(x,x)=u(x,-x)=1$.

My attempt:

I let $\xi=x+t$ and $\nu=x-t$. This transformed the equation into $$-4u_{\xi\mu}+\lambda u=0.$$

This can be written as an integral equation:
$$\frac{u}{\lambda}4=\int_{0}^{\nu}\int_{0}^{\xi}u \ dy\ dz$$

What I want to know:

Is this correct so far? I feel that I've ignored the $u(x,x)=x(x,-x)=1$ condition.

Next, I want to use Picard iteration to get a series solution to this double integral but I do not know how to proceed. For the one dimensional ODE case, the procedure is to show that $u$ is Lipschitz and and then iterate with the initial guess to calculate $\int u.$

Comment: I'm not sure how to deal with the given boundary condition or region but for the Dirichlet boundary condition I think the iteration scheme for $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=\phi(x,t)u+F(x,t)$  is $u_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\int_{x-(t-t')}^{x+(t-t)'} F(x',t')+\phi(x',t')u_0(x',t') \ dx'\ dt'$